# Why VMware player doesn't release the memory when running on Linux while in Windows it does?

Tags: vmware

I've installed VMware player 64bit version 7 (upgraded from 6) for both Windows 7 and CentOS 6.5

I run usually centOS and Fedora as guest VM.

I've observed, that the RAM usage goes up (as it should) on Host OS when I spin multiple guest VM and also when I spin enterprise  applications (IBM Websphere suite) on those guest VM.

On CentOS as host, I don't see RAM release after I shutdown guest VM or shutdown application on guest VM. Even after 15 – 20 min unless I reboot the host OS.

In comparison, when using Windows 7 as host, RAM release almost instantly.

These are same guest VM that I use on both Host OS.

The behavior was same on VMware player version 6.

Is VMware player is better optimized for Win than Linux? If not, what measure can I take to have RAM release when using CentOS as host?

Comment: The hardware where both Host OS run are identical (being a dual boot machine)

Comment: Welcome to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ Raman. You can edit the question that you asked by clicking edit right under the vmware tag. Also take a look at the [about section](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Is VM debugging enabled? Are there anything in the logs?

Comment: Thanks Braiam & jmunsch. Yes, vmware logging is enabled and I'm unable to make anything out of it. Is there a way I can upload/send to this forum? Please advise.

Comment: I would suggest trying to find anything related to memory in the logs, and if you find something, either update your question, or delete this one and ask a more specific question? There is a possibility that someone else is having the same issue so maybe a bug could be open, or a setting is just misconfigured in some way?